# Template in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to develop a website using a templating method I have created different files and would like to run a query and that query would be available on all templates is it possible to do that? Like I would like to give you an example what I am doing here in the controller I have created a variable like this

```
$data['navigation'] = 'templates/main_menu';
$this->load->view('main');
```

Okay so now here what I did in the view of main is I included header and footer there and called the navigation file dynamically like this

```
$this->load->view($navigation);
```

Okay so now What I am trying to do is want to get an icons stored in database and other settings as well so I placed a query in the header file

```
<?php $settings = $this->db->get_where('settings', array('id' => 2));\\ This query is just placed above the doctype in the header file and I would like to be called every where  ?>

templates/main_menu.php
$settings->row()->header_bg_color
```

But I am getting an error as Message: Undefined variable: settings and if i place this settings query within the main_menu.php file it works so like what should be the way i mean it does not make sense to call the query again and again if I would be requiring what will be the best way to do and what is tthe use of model would it be used for the queries if it is then if I place this settings query within the model how would I access it is it possible please advise me

Thank you

Comment: your header file data can't be processed to other view, codeigniter is mvc structure you have to pass the data as argument to be accessed by view e.g. $this->load->view('$navigation', $data); coming to your point what you can do here is create a common function file write your query there and  include it in controller and then pass that data to your views.

Comment: Can you submit it within the asnwer a sample code please as I am new with codeigniter and what if i create within a model should it be able to be called within the views?

Comment: I hope you have got your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi below is code of controller. i have created the common_library.php file in which i have written all common function that I want to use all views.

```
class Maintenance extends CI_Controller {
function Maintenance() {
parent::__construct();
// file for all common function 
    include('application/controllers/common/common_library.php');
    $this->load->model('maintenance_model');
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
}
function index(){
/*
    *   @ desc : default function that loads the maintenance_view.
    *   
    *   
    */
    $data['common_query']   = commonQuery() // define this function in common_library file
    $data['model_data'] = $this->maintenance_model->projectdetail();
    $data['formtitle']  = 'Maintenance List | BMS';

    $this->load->view('maintenance_view',$data);
}
}
```

Comment: It's Better to use HMVC if need to load a controller with in controller.

Comment: @wolfgang1983 if you are pointing to this line include('application/controllers/common/common_library.php'); then just a clarification this is a just common function file not a controller. It's just places in controller folder as I am going to use this file for controller only.